# Substring in linux using cut

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

I would like to grab a substring of a file to get the default password of mysql in centos.
This is the command I am using to get the password:

```
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

which result is:

```
2018-02-21T07:03:11.681201Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: >KkHAt=#z6OV
```

Now, I am using this command to get the password only and remove the unnecessary stuff, so I can use it in a script:

```
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | cut -d ':' -f 4 | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

But using 2 cuts seems very ugly. Is there another command or tool that I can use, or a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '/temporary password/{print $NF}' file
>KkHAt=#z6OV
```

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind that `awk` splits the lines in fields based on a field separator (by default whitspaces) and `NF` refers to the number of fields, you can print the last field with:

```
$ grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | awk '{print $NF}'
```